# How to improve accuracy of a binary classification in neural network

Tags: neural-network, classification, accuracy

I tried to program a binary classifier to predict whether a customer belongs to one class or another.

I have over 200k feature vectors, consisting of numeric 12 features each and assume that should suffice. Of these 200k, 120k are features for the one label, 80k are features for the other label. My problem now is that I cannot get the accuracy of this classifier over 70%. Sure, this is better than chance, but I hoped for something a little more... accurate? Here is my code for the network:

```py
# I have 200k feature vectors with values each; 
# these features include age values between 20 and 80, 
# but also boolean values, so 0 and 1. Therefore I apply a scaler.

minmaxscaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
minmax_features = minmaxscaler.fit_transform(features)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=features[0].shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

BATCH_SIZE = 10000

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2, verbose=1)

hist = model.fit(minmax_features, 
                 labels, 
                 epochs = 100, 
                 shuffle=True, 
                 steps_per_epoch=len(features)/BATCH_SIZE, 
                 validation_split=0.2, 
                 validation_steps=len(features)*0.2/BATCH_SIZE, 
                 callbacks=[early_stop], 
                 verbose=1)
```

Adding another layer or changing the number of nodes on the layer did not change much about the outcome. Does anybody have any advice how I can raise the accuracy of my network?

Comment: Does the accuracy improve with balanced data ? (E.g.: 80k samples of both classes)

Comment: @ShamitVerma No, it does not improve.

Comment: Try reducing batch size, does that improve accuracy ?

Comment: @ShamitVerma What I did now was turn all my categorical data (like year, month, day) into one-hot values instead of scaling them. I get a 100% accuracy now, even for a seperate testing set, which makes me kind of suspicious. But can this be achieved with a binary classifier?

Comment: Just realized that I also one-hot-vectorized the output and accidentally left one of the two columns in the input. I corrected this and am now back to 70%.

Comment: I would try 2 things : 1. load data into something Weka and visually apply some Tree classifier + SVM .    2. Do PCA / t-sne and other exploratory analysis to see if features are really capable of predicting the outcomes.